# Custom Enums - Unknown Type

Tags: objective-c, enums

Moving on with my game a bit I want to add difficulties etc.

Coming to Objective-C from C#, I was hoping I could have some enums like this

```
typedef enum GameTypes{
    Classic = 0,
    Unlimited,
    Timed,
    Expert,
} GameType;

typedef enum GameDifficultys
{
    Easy = 0,
    Medium,
    Hard,
} GameDifficulty;
```

and then have something like this:

```
GameType gameType = GameTypes.Classic;
GameDifficulty gameDifficulty = GameDifficultys.Easy;
```

However I get this following error:

```
Unknown type name "GameType"/"GameDifficulty"
```

Is this possible like it is in C#?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C#` is one of the worst things to ever happen to `C`.

Your question has nothing to do with Objective-C, it's a plain C question.

```
typedef enum GameTypes{
    Classic = 0,
    Unlimited,
    Timed,
    Expert,
} GameType;
```

That code does several things (of which I will only describe the easy ones).  First, it declares an enumeration type, which can be used as `enum GameTypes`.  For example:

```
enum GameTypes gameType = Classic;
```

Second, it puts those 4 names into the global namespace, such that `Classic`, `Unlimited`, `Timed`, and `Expert` can be used, and must not be duplicated as symbols.

Third, it creates a type alias called `GameType` which can be used as an alias for `enum GameTypes`.

So, for your specific example, you should not differentiate `enum GameTypes` and `GameType`.  Instead, you should probably do something like this:

```
typedef enum GameType {
    GameTypeClassic = 0,
    GameTypeUnlimited,
    GameTypeTimed,
    GameTypeExpert,
} GameType;

typedef enum GameDifficulty
{
    GameDifficultyEasy = 0,
    GameDifficultyMedium,
    GameDifficultyHard,
} GameDifficulty;
```

and then...

```
GameType gameType = GameTypeClassic;
GameDifficulty gameDifficulty = GameDifficultyEasy;
```

Also, you do not have to assign the first element as `0` because the first element of an enumeration will always get `0` unless it is explicitly overridden.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have defined the enums wrong. In C the following seems to be the convention:

```
typedef enum {
    Classic = 0,
    Unlimited,
    Timed,
    Expert,
} GameTypes;

typedef enum
{
    Easy = 0,
    Medium,
    Hard,
} GameDifficulties;
```

Even so, I'd stick with Apple's naming conventions when using enums in Objective-C, which would result in something like:

```
typedef enum {
    GameTypeClassic = 0,
    GameTypeUnlimited,
    GameTypeTimed,
    GameTypeExpert,
} GameType;

typedef enum
{
    GameDifficultyEasy = 0,
    GameDifficultyMedium,
    GameDifficultyHard,
} GameDifficulty;
```

Now you'll be able to assign values like this:

```
GameType gameType = GameTypeClassic;
GameDifficulty gameDifficulty = GameDifficultyEasy;
```

Check how enums are defined in UITableView.h for comparison: https://github.com/enormego/UIKit/blob/master/UITableView.h